# Solana check all spl token balances of a wallet

Tags: javascript, node.js, solana

I'm using solana json rpc api to check a wallet's token balance from my javascript app. I have used the function for it like this

```
const getTokenBalance = async (walletAddress, tokenMintAddress) => {
  const response = await axios({
    url: `https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com`,
    method: "post",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    data: {
      jsonrpc: "2.0",
      id: 1,
      method: "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
      params: [
        walletAddress,
        {
          mint: tokenMintAddress,
        },
        {
          encoding: "jsonParsed",
        },
      ],
    },
  });
  if (
    Array.isArray(response?.data?.result?.value) &&
    response?.data?.result?.value?.length > 0 &&
    response?.data?.result?.value[0]?.account?.data?.parsed?.info?.tokenAmount
      ?.amount > 0
  ) {
    return (
      Number(
        response?.data?.result?.value[0]?.account?.data?.parsed?.info
          ?.tokenAmount?.amount
      ) / 1000000000
    );
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
};
```

However I want to get all the token balance by one call instead of asking a token balance by giving a mint address for every token out there which makes my api respond like 10 minutes, is there any friendly way to do that?

I saw [Covalent api](https://www.covalenthq.com/docs/api/#get-/v1/%7Bchain_id%7D/address/%7Baddress%7D/balances_v2/) can do it for checking ethereum wallet balance, wonder how they can do it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the standard RPC accept batch requests, you should be able to send an array of all the requests you want, note that response will be an array as well.

```
// For example

const response = await axios({
    url: `https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com`,
    method: "post",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    data: [
        {
          jsonrpc: "2.0",
          id: 1,
          method: "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
          params: [
            walletAddress,
            {
              mint: tokenMintAddress,
            },
            {
              encoding: "jsonParsed",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          jsonrpc: "2.0",
          id: 1,
          method: "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
          params: [
            walletAddress2,
            {
              mint: tokenMintAddress2,
            },
            {
              encoding: "jsonParsed",
            },
          ],
        },
    ]
});
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you if it will work!

Comment: The answer is correct, just if you exceed 256 objects that we pass into the data array, it will throw too big request error with code 413,=. So I just call every token by iterating over tokens array and calling the api with 256 objects in every call. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having 429 error Too many requests with more than 1 object in the array. You don't have that error?

Comment: Yes I started to have getting this error also, seems they did put rate limiting to their api, so right now there are 12.000+ tokens available in solana blockchain, so we need to ask roughly 60 times to ask for every contract if given wallet address have tokens or not, I think we need some sort of caching in that case

Answer (score 2):

As all tokens (that follow the standard) are "childs" of the Token Program you can get all with one RPC call :

```
curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: 
application/json" -d ' {                                                                                
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"getTokenAccountsByOwner",
    "params": [
       "walletAddress",
      {
        "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
      }, 
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed"
      }
    ],
    "id":4
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actully 4 ways to fetch balance of tokens

1. Solana CLI
2. Solana-Web3.js (Worked for me) using getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, provider, mintPublicKey, provider.publicKey)
3. cURL
4. Rust

All method details are mentioned in the below link.

https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/getting-started/how-to-look-up-the-balance-of-a-solana-wallet

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35317807)

Answer (score -1):

If u need to get a balance of ur own token u can used the json rpc api with the follow post.

```
    curl https://api.devnet.solana.com/ -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
    "params": [
      "uja3w9XG1g6DQSVT6YASK99FVmdVwXoHVoQEgtEJdLv",
      {
        "mint": "7TMzmUe9NknkeS3Nxcx6esocgyj8WdKyEMny9myDGDYJ"
      },
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed"
      }
    ]
  }
'
```